# How do I remove texts in brackets only from the beginning of lines with regex in Python?

Tags: python, regex

I would like to remove all the line codes in brackets placed at the beginning of lines but want to preserve the other words in brackets.

***NOTE**:
In the application that I use I cannot import any Python library but can use Python regexes. The regex and the replacement value in the substitution have to be separated by a comma. For example, I use `([^\s\d])(-\s+),\1` to merge hyphenated words at the end of lines. So I would need something similar.*

`\([^()]*\)` finds every text in brackets.

`^\h*\([^()]*\)` finds only the first one but not the rest.
How should I modify it?

The sample text is the following:

```
(#p0340r#) This is a sentence. This is another one but I need more sentences to fill the space to start a new line.
(#p0350q#) Why? (this text should be left unchanged)
(#p0360r#) Because I need to remove these codes from interview texts.
```

The expected outcome should be:

```
This is a sentence. This is another one but I need more sentences 
to fill the space to start a new line.
Why? (this text should be left unchanged)
Because I need to remove these codes from interview texts.
```

Thank you!

Comment: Please format the sample input text as _code_, by prepending 4 or more spaces to each line.  It would also be helpful to see the expected output you want.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using ^ to match beginning of line in Python regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31400362/using-to-match-beginning-of-line-in-python-regex)

Comment: Well, it turns out it is any Python code related question.

Answer (score 1):

To remove a pattern at the start of any line with Python `re.sub` (or any `re.sub` powered search and replace), you need to use the `^` before the pattern (that is what you already have) *and* pass the multiline `(?m)` flag (if you have access to code you could use `flags=re.M`).

Also, `\h` is not Python `re` compliant, you need to use a construct like `[ \t]` or `[^\S\n]` (in some rare cases, also `[^\S\r\n]`, usually when you read a file in binary mode) to match any horizontal whitespace.

So you can use

```
(?m)^[^\S\n]*\([^()]*\)[^\S\n]*
```

and replace with an empty string.

Note: if you ever want to remove one or more substrings inside parentheses at the start of a line group the pattern and apply the `+` quantifier on it:

```py
(?m)^(?:[^\S\n]*\([^()]*\))+[^\S\n]*
#    ^^^                  ^^
```

Comment: Thank you, Viktor. The above codes are perfect. But in the application that I use I cannot import any Python library but can use Python regexes. The regex and the replacement value in the substitution have to be separated by a comma. For example, I use ([^\s\d])(-\s+),\1 to merge hyphenated words at the end of lines. So I would need something similar.

Comment: @learner2021 As I wrote, `re.M` can be used as an inline modifier `(?m)`. So, the pattern is `(?m)^[^\S\n]*\([^()]*\)[^\S\n]*`, the replacement is just an empty string. Sorry, it is a site where programming issues are resolved, it is not a 3rd party support forum.

Comment: Superb! Cheers!!!!

Comment: @learner2021 If you still have trouble with this issue, please update the question.